# Change name JSON whit map function JS

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the following array:

```
var kvArray = [
            {userId: 1, id: 1,title: "sunt"},
            {userId: 1, id: 2,title: "qui"},
            {userId: 1, id: 3, title: "repell"}
          ]
```

But, I want to change the `name` in JSON, I used this function but I don't get how to do with the other names:

```
var reformattedArray = kvArray.map(function(obj){ 
var rObj = {};
rObj[obj.userId] = obj.firts;
return rObj;
});
```

the idea is to transform it as follows

```
//   reformattedArray = [
//              {first: 1, second: 1, third: "sunt"},
//              {first: 1, second: 2, third: "qui"},
//              {first: 1, second: 3, third: "repell"}
//              ]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you explain why you want to do this? Instead of "first", "second", etc, can you not use an array? E.g. `reformattedArray[0][0]` instead of `reformattedArray[0].first`. See [what is the x-y problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: `obj.firts` is undefined

Comment: Note that the order of properties is defined in ES2015+ (aka "ES6+"), but relying on it (which you would need to above) is **almost never** a good idea.

Comment: Also note that this has nothing whatsoever to do with JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Please demonstrate enough respect for the people you're asking for help to proofread your question before clicking the "Post Your Question" button.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign all the properties explicitly.

```js
var kvArray = [
    {userId: 1, id: 1,title: "sunt"},
    {userId: 1, id: 2,title: "qui"},
    {userId: 1, id: 3, title: "repell"}
];
var reformattedArray = kvArray.map(({userId, id, title}) => 
    ({first: userId, second: id, third: title}));
console.log(reformattedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following would accomplish that:

```
let newArray = kvArray.map((elm) => {
    let mappedElm = { first: elm.userId, second: elm.id, third: elm.title};
    return mappedElm;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the map function, you can create a new object with the values you want:

```
var refformattedArray = kvArray.map(function(obj) { 
    var rObj = {
        first: obj.userId,
        second: obj.id,
        third: obj.title
    };
    return rObj;
});
```